# Number of ways to get a sum of ten using numbers from 1 to 10.

Tags: combinatorics

My question is if I want to get a sum of 10 using numbers from 1 to 10 without restrictions on repetitions or number of steps of calculations. And the order of my calculation matters, which means that 2+8 and 8+2 are two different ways of getting a 10.
How many ways I can get a sum of 10?

My attempt: I will think this question as I have 10 blocks and I need to either fill in or not fill in a block. I will count number of ways that I can fill the blocks which is $2^{10}$. If I fill all 10 blocks that is my 10 on its own. If I fill first 8 blocks and have a block empty and fill the last block, that is my 8+2. If I fill the first 5 then one blank, fill the next 2 then 1 blank and last one filled. That is my 5+3+2. The blank block is where I stop counting, and they all sum up to 10.

Comment: Edit: Disregard, see @neihmban's comment below. --HINT: You are looking for **partitions** of 10.--

Comment: No, he is looking for **compositions** of $10$: *“And the order of my calculation matters, which means that 2+8 and 8+2 are two different ways of getting a 10.”*

Comment: @nejimban, non-cofee brain be like. Sry.

Comment: The first block cannot be empty, so the right answer is $2^{10-1}$. Indeed, the formula for such problem is $2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 3):

- Consider $10\;\; 1's$ in a row $(1\;1\;1\;....1)$
- Invent a new sign, $\color{red}{\;)+(}$
- In the $9$ gaps between the $1's,$ either put a $\;\color{blue}{+}\;$ or $\color{red}{)+(}$,
  eg $(1\color{blue}{+1}\;$$\color{red}{)+(}$$\;1\color{blue}{+}....)$

Since we can choose either of the two symbols in the interstices between the $1's\;$to break up the number , the number of distinct outcomes will be $2^9 = 512$

The technical name for breaking up a number in this manner is called a **composition** of a number